# Error label only show once event all inputs are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a form with conditions, when one of each `input` or all empty, it will create `span` on `label`.

**HTML :**

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" class="testform" >
      <legend>test</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">username :</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control m-20">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">password :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control m-20">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="repassword">re-type password :</label>
        <input type="password" id="repassword" class="form-control m-20">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email :</label>
        <input type="Email" id="email" class="form-control m-20">
      </div>                        
      <button id="send" class="btn btn-primary">
        submit
      </button>
 </form>
```

On js code. I try to check with change the label's background to green if the input is empty and its work.

Then I try to create the span on label with prepend. but when I run it, only the label email got span. if I fill only for email. only repassword's label got span. I didn't find that when I only use code for change background.

Anyone find what is wrong. thanks

**JS :**

```
// button submit got clicked
$('#send').on("click", function(){ 
    var input= $('.testform input');
    var empty= $("<span class=\"error\">empty</span>");
    // check input if have value if empty
    input.each(function() {
        var self=this;
        var value=$(this).val();
        // if empty change color of label
        if(value ==""){
            // $(self).parent(".form-group").find("label").prepend(empty);
            $(self).parent(".form-group").find("label").css({"background": "green"});
        }else{
            $(self).parent(".form-group").find("label").css({"background": "white"});
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happen because you're trying to assign the same element `empty` to all the inputs and that impossible so it will assigned just to the last input, so instead you should `clone` the `empty` element every time you want to assign it :

```
$(this).parent(".form-group").find("label").prepend(empty.clone(true));
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#send').on("click", function(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.error').remove();
  var $inputs= $('.testform input');
  var empty= '<span class="error">empty</span>';

  $inputs.each(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    var value=$(this).val();

    if(value ==""){
      $this.parent(".form-group").find("label").prepend(empty);
      $this.parent(".form-group").find("label").css({"background": "green"});
    }else{
      $this.parent(".form-group").find("label").css({"background": "white"});
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post" role="form" accept-charset="utf-8" class="testform" >
  <legend>test</legend>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">username :</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control m-20">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">password :</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control m-20">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="repassword">re-type password :</label>
    <input type="password" id="repassword" class="form-control m-20">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email :</label>
    <input type="Email" id="email" class="form-control m-20">
  </div>                        
  <button id="send" class="btn btn-primary">
    submit
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You could also simply make it `var empty= '<span class="error">empty</span>';`and avoid the cloning. +1

Comment: i see you change from `$(self).parent` to `$(this).parent` , does it make it buggy too?

Comment: Thanks @DelightedD0D for you intervention/advice.

Comment: @vandi actually, I would cache `this` like `var $this=$(this);` as it makes it clear that it is a jQuery object. see http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/66/ more personal prefference than anything though

Comment: The jQuery object `$(this)` will not change inside each so using `$(this)` will work just fine as you could see in my snippet.

Comment: Sure it will work, but you're recreating the jQuery object multiple times. Obviously the performance implications in this small bit of code would be miniscule but I'd say its good practice to always cache jQuery objects you will be using more than once, in fact, my IDE (PHPStorm) practically yells at me if I dont cache objects used more than once.

Comment: Thanks again, updated my answer with you suggestion.